# C# double to integer conversion truncation

Tags: c#, integer, double

I want to know why the following codes yields in the result "23".

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double a = 1.2d;
        double b = 0.05d;
        var val = (int)(a/b);
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}`
```

Example code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BsFoY3

I do understand the 'truncation towards zero' principle. But how exactly does the double lose it's precision to < 24.0d in this example?

Thanks!

Comment: Never expect exactitude when working with `float` or `double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubles are approximations.  Try this code:

```
double a = 1.2d;
double b = 0.05d;

Console.WriteLine($"{a:f20}   {b:f20}");
Console.WriteLine($"{a / b:f20}");
```

It outputs:

```
1.19999999999999995559   0.05000000000000000278
23.99999999999999644729
```

and, when you cast `23.99999999999999644729` to an `int`, it's `23`.